# Flutter TextInputType change gives error in Form

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, android-textinputlayout

While changing keyboard type from `TextInputType.text` to `TextInputType.phone` inside `Form` receiving this error:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13712): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13712): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13712): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

The widget is `StatefulWidget`

Comment: can you show code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call them errors (or at least not breaking errors because they won't crash the app)

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9471) long  and **still open** issue on github addresses the problem and there seem to be no way to stop these warnings (until now) that are being caused by clearing the `TextField`